# How do I get the second Item in an Iteration?

Tags: foreach, smarty

**I get the first item like this:**

```
{foreach $sArticle.sBlockPrices as $blockPrice}
  {if $blockPrice@first}
    First element
  {else}
    ...
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

How do I get the second/third item?

Answer (score 0):

Use the index property of foreach referenced here: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Try something like this:

```
{foreach name=$sArticle.sBlockPrices item=$blockPrice name=blockPrices}
  {if $smarty.foreach.blockPrices.index == 2}
    ...
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```